# Zcat with lines' indexes

Tags: linux, zcat

How can I see the indexes of lines with zcat? 
I tried to find a flag of zcat, but didn't find one that show lines' numbers.

Example:
My file contains these lines:

```
Hello everybody!
aaa bbb
aaa Hello
```

What I want to get from this command:

```
zcat file | grep Hello
```

Is:

```
1 Hello everybody! 
3 aaa Hello
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **-n** flag with **grep** command in order to view the line number.

`$ zcat hello.zip | grep -n "Hello"
1:Hello everybody!
3:aaa Hello
ubuntu14@ubuntu14:~/Public$`